# How can I print a x by x matrix in C?

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, printf

```
int main() {
    char gameArea[][8] = {
        {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
        {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
        {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
        {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
        {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
        {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
        {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
        {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'}};
    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    while (i<8) {
        while (j<8) {
            printf("%c",gameArea[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
XXXXXXXX
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.563 s
Press any key to continue.
```

In theory, the `i` would run through the columns, and print all of it, but that's not what happened. I thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want a for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
        printf("%c", gameArea[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This is the progression of your loops:

- `i = 0` and `j = 0`, print `X` and increment `j`.
- ...
- `i = 0` and `j = 7`, print `X` and increment `j`.
- Since `j = 8`, stop `j`-loop and increment `i`.
- `i = 1` but `j` is still `8` as we cannot perform `j`-loop, so increment `i`.
- ...
- `i = 7` but `j` is still `8` as we cannot perform `j`-loop, so increment `i`.
- Now `i = 8` so stop `i`-loop.

What you want to do is after the `j`-loop when you increment `i` you also want to reset `j` to `0`. Along with that, you want to print a new-line for the next row otherwise you'll end up with 64 consecutive `X`s.

Using a for-loop:

```
for (/*initialization*/; /*condition*/; /*increment*/) {
    /*loop body*/
}
```

Is a short-cut for doing this with a while-loop:

```
/*initialization*/
while(/*condition*/) {
    /*loop body*/
    /*increment*/
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set j back to zero after each inner loop

```
    printf("%c",gameArea[i][j]);
    j++;
}
j = 0;
i++;
```

But `for` loop is more suitable for your task, as stated in other answers.

Comment: A `for` loop would be better in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

After the first `while (j<8)` loop, nothing resets `j` to 0, similarly for `i`, so the loops only run once, hence only one row is printed.

Consider using `for` loops:

`for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)`

Also, did you try debugging the code, i.e. setting breakpoints and stepping through the execution?

Answer (score 1):

The `j` counter needs to be initialised at the start of each i loop.

What's happening is j is looped once, at the end j is 8 so the j loop is only iterated once.

```
while (i<8) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j<8) {
        printf("%c",gameArea[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `j` to 0 at the beginning of the first while loop, so that on each iteration, you can still loop through the inner one. Otherwise, once j is equal to 8, the inner loop will not be entered anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a `j=0`:

```
while (i<8) {
 j = 0; 
 while (j<8) {
      printf("%c",gameArea[i][j]);
      j++;
   }
 i++;
}
```

Without it your inner loop will be executed only once, since `j` never changes after the first run and the loop condition is not met again.

As other users suggested, you might want to use for loops with sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0; int j = 0;
while (i<8) {
    while (j<8) {
         printf("%c",gameArea[i][j]);
         j++;
    }
    i++;
    printf("\n")
}
```